# File Explorer groups files by Date and not Name

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I just upgraded to the Windows 10 May 2019 update (1903) and File Explorer now groups my files by date instead of the folders at the top then alphabetical for the files. How do I change this back?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have Group By enabled. Just go to Group By, then select '(None)'

[image]

Comment: @jacob did this work?